# SQL-PHP Grabbing information from end of URL and compare with row in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, api, substr

Ok so this uses two things, One is vbulletins forums with a steam plugin which allows users to register on my forums using there steam account, It also uses API from a website at http://7daystodie-servers.com which is a voting site that has API I can use as a reward system in one way or another. Everything I have been doing works good so far the only problem I have now is updating the vbulletin database with the correct information if $pullinfo == 1, Here is my code as is.

```
$connection = mysql_connect("$hostname","$data_username","$data_password") or die ("Couldn't connect to server.");
$db = mysql_select_db("$db_name", $connection) or die("Couldn't select database.");
$sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT steam_link, username FROM user WHERE steam_link IS NOT NULL AND TRIM(steam_link) <> '' AND username IS NOT NULL AND TRIM(username) <> ''");

while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql1)){
    $steamid = substr($row1[steam_link], 0, 17);
    $checkvoted = 'http://7daystodie-servers.com/api/?object=votes&element=claim&key=wc5ablok4zpc1w3ljgofp5yuuedrgv8ycs6&steamid='.$steamid;
    $pullinfo = file_get_contents($checkvoted);
    if ($pullinfo == 2){
        echo ''.$row1[username].' has already claimed reward for voting...<br />';
    }
    if ($pullinfo == 1){
        $username = $row1[username];
        echo ''.$row1[username].' has not claimed reward for voting...<br />';
        $sql2 = mysql_query("UPDATE user SET `reputation`=(`reputation`+10) WHERE substr($row[steam_link], 0, 17) = $steamid");
    }
    if ($pullinfo == 0){
        echo ''.$row1[username].' has not voted...<br />';
    }
    echo ''.$row1[username].''.$pullinfo.'<br />';
}
```

As you can see it does two things, One is gets the information from the API url which is a "0" or a "1" then I am trying to update the database information based on one factor, $row[steam_link] and $steamid. Issue I have is both of these are pulled from the database from the start they are the same thing. So how would I compair the return of the API with the $steamid so I can UPDATE database?

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: Understand that they are deprecated but I have not had time to study any PDO or mysqli to see what is what so would really like some help with this so I have it temp live until I can write with PDO or MySQLi

Comment: The only difference I have seen with mysql, and mysqli is the "i".  I haven't had a chance to read the technical side of it though..  Just add the i

Comment: @EricSSH If I am not mistaken MySQLi is safer to use and protect yourself from things like injections but that's if I am not mistaken, Its just better code the I stands for "Improved" so I guess no one wants to use the old MySQL when they have the improved stuff, I just need to check all that has changed. But no matter if I use MySQLi or not, I would still need help with my question as I would still have the same problem not matter if I used MySQL or MySQLi.

Comment: What is `$pullinfo = file_get_contents($checkvoted);
    if ($pullinfo == 2){` doing?

Comment: It is pulling a value from the API link of 0, 1, or 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your UPDATE statement needs to identify which rows are to be updated.

The SELECT statement pulled `steam_link` and `username` columns, seems likely that these are the columns you want to reference in predicates in the UPDATE statement.

Since the original SELECT had a DISTINCT keyword, and the query was from the `user` table, we assume that there may be multiple rows in the table with the same `username` and `steam_link`, and that we may only want to add reputation to one of those rows.

```
$sql = "UPDATE user u
           SET u.reputation = u.reputation + 10
         WHERE u.steam_link = '" . mysql_real_escape_string( $row1['steam_link'] ) . "'
           AND u.username   = '" . mysql_real_escape_string( $row1['username'] ) . "'
         LIMIT 1"; 
if(!mysql_query($sql)) {
    echo "error: " . mysql_error();
}
```

But, I'm just guessing which rows in `user` table you want to update, all of the rows that have `username` and `steamlink` matching values pulled by the query, or all of the rows with a matching `username`, or all rows with a matching `steam_link`. (I'm just guessing.)

---

Your existing code has a references to `$row`; we see `$row1` being assigned values, but we don't see any assignments to `$row`.

I'm seeing what looks like array references `$row1[username]`, but string keys are usually enclosed in single quotes, e.g. `$row1['username']`.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

If we want to match rows that have `steam_link` column starting with a specific set of characters, for example, 17 specific digit characters `79546325458103548`, we could use a `LIKE` comparison operator in a predicate (that is, a condition in the WHERE clause:

```
AND u.steam_link LIKE '79 5463 25458103548%'
```

Note that the `'%'` character at the end is a special wildcard character (in the context of the right side of a LIKE comparison). That will match any number of characters (zero, one or more)

If we want a more specific match, 17 specific digits, followed by exactly one character that is a '0' or '1' digit character, we could use a regular expression comparison:

```
AND u.steam_link REGEXP '^79546325458103548[10]$`
```

As another option, we could also use a SUBSTRING function around the `steam_link` column, but we typically try to avoid doing that when possible, we prefer to use comparisons against bare columns when possible.

There are lots of other alternatives that would accomplish the same thing as the expressions above. If we wanted to do the same thing as the REGEXP as above, we could do something overly obfuscated and tedious:

```
AND SUBSTRING(u.steam_link,1,2) = '79'
AND SUBSTRING(u.steam_link,3,4) = '5463'
AND SUBSTRING(u.steam_link,7,9) = '254581035'
AND SUBSTRING(u.steam_link,16,3) IN ('480','481')
```

If we wanted to match just the 18th character of `steam_link`:

```
AND SUBSTRING(u.steam_link,18,1) = '0'
```

It's still not clear (to me) which rows you want to update. But maybe this helps you with some ideas about what is possible.

Comment: Yea my php sql is very pore. One of the things going on is the row steam_link contains data like 79546325458103548|0|1 and I had to use substr($row1[steam_link], 0, 17) in an array to pull all users from the database and pass to the url to read 79546325458103548, Now the API only replies back with a value of 0,1,or 2 so I need to update the database based on the why I pulled the data out of the database because the 79546325458103548 will no longer match the database value of 79546325458103548|0|1 and the API only returns 0, 1, or 2 so I am stuck on what to do.